# Accessing 2D arrays using x86 Assembler

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I am currently testing various methods of speeding up my code using x86 assembler. I've been able to access 1D arrays in the past but 2D arrays seem to be completely different!

I'm using two for loops which I've created in assembly and have moved 'x' into the ECX register and 'y' into the EDX register.

I've also loaded the effective address of the array into EBX by using this:

```
lea ebx,dword ptr [slimeTrail]
```

Now what I want to do is use the loops to isolate a character and move it into the AL register by using:

```
movsx al,byte ptr [ebx + (ecx * sizeX) + edx]
```

where sizeX is the width.

However, the errors I am getting are

`error C2404: 'edx' : illegal register in 'second operand'`

and

`error C2425: '*' : non-constant expression in 'second operand'`

I've checked the Intel manuals and don't seem to be getting there. Have I missed something basic?

Comment: To acces a 2d array you want to [x + (width * y)]. Not sure what ebx is in your example.....

Comment: What exactly is `sizeX`? Is it a constant or a variable?

Comment: "speeding up my code using x86 assembler"... Hmmm. Let's bet, that [IPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Performance_Primitives) library + Intel Compiler with special switches + rearranging data and code in **C++** will be faster then "speeding using assembler"

Comment: I also agree that the compiler can do a better job at speeding up your application.

Comment: @borisbn In the end you may not even need *IPP* and special compiler switches to be slower than the compiler if you're not that much of an assembler pro (which I have a feeling the OP indeed isn't).

Comment: @ChristianRau: It's in fact almost guaranteed that todays compilers will beat you at picking registers and scheduling memory read/writes.

Comment: @ChristianRau It's my fault, that I did miss `C++` in the name of the compiler. Let me repair:  Let's bet, that `writing in C++ using` IPP library + Intel `C++` Compiler with special switches + rearranging data and code in `C++` will be faster then "speeding using assembler"

Comment: @borisbn Huh? My comment (which was a mere generalization of yours) still aplies, so what? Of course I know that you didn't talk about assembler programming, that's what my whole comment (and yours) was about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn addressing of memory operands.

In 32-bit mode you're typically limited to using one of the following as the address of a memory operand in a single instruction:

- register
- displacement (constant)
- register + displacement
- register1 + register2 * scale + displacement (scale is a constant: 1, 2, 4 or 8)

Your `ebx + (ecx * sizeX) + edx` is neither of the above.

If `sizeX` is neither of 1, 2, 4 and 8, you must multiply `ecx` by it using either `mul` or `imul` or some other equivalent operation (consisting of several instructions) and add the product to `ebx` or `edx` and after that you can do `mov al,byte ptr [ebx + edx]`.

Btw, `movsx al, ...` makes no sense is probably invalid. A simple `mov` will do.

Comment: SizeX is the constant width of the array = 30
SizeY is the constant height of the array = 20

The C++ code is:
for (int x=1; x < SIZEX-1; x++)
  for (int y=1; y < SIZEY-1; y++)
  { 
     if (slimeTrail [y][x] > 0)
     { 
 slimeTrail [y][x] --;   
 if (slimeTrail [y][x] == 0)  
      garden [y][x] = BLANK;
     }
   }

I'm trying to use assembler to cycle through the slimeTrail array, pulling out each character and then I can do a comparison. I'm just not sure how to access each part of the array